# How to add nested arrays into firestore database using react?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nested-object

I have an object in my react code as below.

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
        groupName: '',
        groupDescription: '',
        priv: []
    });
```

After setInputs to above state, I execute the below function.

```
    const addDataToFb = () => {
        console.log(inputs)
            firebase.firestore().collection('userGroups').add(inputs)
                .then(() => {
                    alert('Group successfully created')
                    resetButtonHandler();
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    alert(err)
                })
    }
```

The console has logged below details.
[Refer this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P82dO.png)

Comment: I got an answer. This error happens becouse of the undefined values in my object. So i put empty string to priv.privDesc. Now its working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit `undefined` values to Firestore, as displayed in your image, as Firestore throws an error when you submit them.

You can turn this behaviour off by adding the following property when initialising Firestore:

`{ignoreUndefinedProperties: true}`